# Selecting only rows with multiple entries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `#DEL_FAC` where I need to select rows which have multiple entries. I used a partition function but I not able to figure out to weed out the rows which has only one single entry based on `Rec_ID`.

Below example will explain little better. So, from the output I would prefer to select `REC_ID` values which has multiple entries. In this example `Rec_ID = 1052`, `12811` and `1321` are the desired results.

I don't want to explicitly mention these `Rec_ID` in the `WHERE` clause since the table has hundred's of rows. This was just an example. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT 
    ID, NAME,
    Rec_ID, CREATED,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rec_ID 
                       ORDER BY (SELECT 01)) AS rn
FROM   
    #DEL_FAC
WHERE  
    CREATED = 'User_1';
```

Output:

```
ID      Name                        Rec_ID       Created    RN
----------------------------------------------------------------      
15755   MARBLE MFG                  1032          User_1    1
17186   COMPRESSOR                  1033          User_1    1
15711   Bakery Solutions            1052          User_1    1
15931   BAKERY SOLUTIONS - FROZEN   1052          User_1    2
16182   Ceramics Inc                 128          User_1    1
16509   E-Z-G                      12811          User_1    1
17836   E-Z-Go, Company            12811          User_1    2
15940   LANDFILL                    1321          User_1    1
15182   LANDFILL- MAINT             1321          User_1    2
16291   Landfill -3                 1321          User_1    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
   SELECT ID
 , NAME
 , Rec_ID
 , CREATED
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Rec_ID ORDER BY
                    (
                        SELECT 01
                    )) AS rn
FROM   #DEL_FAC
WHERE  CREATED = 'User_1'
  AND rec_id in (select rec_id from #dec_fac
                 group by rec_id
                 having count(rec_id) > 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do any partitioning, you can just obtain the list by use of `HAVING` doing a count on `Rec_ID`:

```
SELECT Rec_ID
FROM #DEL_FAC
WHERE CREATED = 'User_1'
GROUP BY Rec_ID
HAVING COUNT(Rec_ID) > 1;
```

Comment: OP wants the detail tho, so this would need to be part of a subquery returning the list of IDS to select from the original dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Or...

```
select Name, Rec_ID, Created from #DEL_FAC
where Rec_ID in
(
    select Rec_ID from #DEL_FAC
    where Created = 'User_1'
    group by Rec_ID
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put an inner WHERE clause so you can select all the rows having User_1 as CREATED and the Rec_ID belonging to the set of multiple Rec_IDs

```
SELECT ID, NAME, Rec_ID, CREATED FROM #DEL_FAC
   WHERE  CREATED = 'User_1' AND Rec_ID IN (
     SELECT Rec_ID 
     FROM #DEL_FAC
     GROUP BY Rec_ID
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
)
```